# number of times one can fetch comments from facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any limit, which restricts the number of times I can fetch comments of posts from a facebook page?

I'm trying to fetch comments from a facebook page with a long term access token.
But when I'm performing the get request for the first time, I'm getting the below error:

```
Error in callAPI(url = url, token = token) : 
  (#32) Page request limit reached
Called from: callAPI(url = url, token = token)
```

I've been requesting data from this page with an older token, for the past one year. Now, I've generated a new token and getting the below error with my first `GET` request.

My maximum request per day is not more than 1000.
Language Used: `R Programming`
Package Used: `Rfacebook`

Note: Not talking of the 4800 requests for a user within 24hrs.

Comment: All you need to know about Rate Limiting is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting

Comment: I've gone through this document. But, I'm just making GET calls an no point in dynamically modifying the x-page-usage header because, it's already giving me error in the response$content json.

Comment: What are you even talking about, that header is _sent to you_ as part of the _response from Facebook_, you could not even “modify” it if you tried ... _“it's already giving me error”_ - that’s because you _already_ made too many calls.

Comment: I was under the impression that if I modify the x-page-usage after making a GET request and then POST the request back to facebook, the x-page-usage header will be modified and I'll be able to fetch data again. But that is not the case. I need to wait till it's reset and then make the GET calls.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by holding the request job for one or two days.
Once it's reset, I'm able to fetch data again.